# Replace character with indent and line break in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach, indentation, line-breaks

is there a way to use foreach and replace on text file to change a character with linebreak and x number of indents? Peculiar request, but it is to make it readible in another program.

Sample text:

> dyreriket|{Animalia}
>   !leddormer@{Annelida}
>   ¤igler${Clitellata}

The symbols |, !, @, ¤, $ and many more should be replace with linebreak and a given number of indents.  I can make the indents work, but not the linebreaks. There is no response when using `n, it only removes the original character. So far I've been playing around with this code.

```
$t1 = '\@';
$r1 = "`n`t`t";
$t2='\¤';
$r2="`n";

Get-Content C:\arter\test.txt `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace $t1, $r1; } `
    |ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace $t2, $r2; } `
    | Out-File  C:\arter\test2.txt ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a line-by-line text replacement like this:

```
$searchText = '[|!@☼$]';
$replacementText = "`r`n`t`t";

Get-Content -Path Input.txt `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace $searchText, $replacementText; } `
    | Out-File -FilePath Output.txt;
```

That uses [regular expression character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z.aspx) to replace all occurrences of the `|`, `!`, `@`, `☼`, or `$` characters in `Input.txt` with a linefeed followed by a carriage return followed by two tabs and writes the resulting text to `Output.txt`.  To perform a case-insensitive search, use the `-replace` or `-ireplace` operators.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I get some inconsistent results that might be due to reserved characters or something. When trying to replace | it adds 't between every single character in the document. And it ignores the 'n.

Comment: The replacement text parameter of the `-replace` operator is a [.NET regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az24scfc.aspx).  Pipe is a special character in regular expressions, so you'll need to escape it as `'\|'`.  Note that you're escaping it for the .NET regular expression engine and not PowerShell, which is why you use backslash instead of backtick.

Comment: Aah. that explain some of it, but the line breaks still doesn't work :S Here's the code as I've typed it.`$searchText = '\|';
$replacementText = "`n`t`t";

Get-Content C:\arter\final1.txt `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace $searchText, $replacementText; } `
    | Out-File  C:\arter\final2.txt ; `

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you're using and some sample text on which you're performing the search-and-replace?  I think the comment box is misinterpreting some of your backticks.

Comment: Please see my updated answer above.  That works for me on the sample text you provided.

Comment: Still nothing happens with the line break :S Does the encoding of the text file matter? Or how it's been made?

Comment: Try `$replacementText = "\`r\`n\`t\`t";`.  I forgot that `\`n` is just an LF instead of CR-LF, and since I was using Notepad++ it still rendered the output what appeared to be correctly.  It wasn't until I enabled the display of whitespace characters that I noticed the missing carriage returns.